# Substract one datetime column after a groupby with a time reference for each group from a second Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have one dataframe df1 with one admissiontime for each id.

```
id     admissiontime    
1      2117-04-03 19:15:00  
2      2117-10-18 22:35:00  
3      2163-10-17 19:15:00  
4      2149-01-08 15:30:00  
5      2144-06-06 16:15:00
```

And an another dataframe df2 with several datetame for each id

```
id      datetime        
1       2135-07-28 07:50:00.000         
1       2135-07-28 07:50:00.000         
2       2135-07-28 07:57:15.900             
3       2135-07-28 07:57:15.900         
3       2135-07-28 07:57:15.900
```

I would like to substract for each id, datetimes with his specific admissiontime, in a column of the second dataframe.

I think I have to use d2.group.by('id')['datetime']- something but I struggle to connect with the df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by another `DataFrame`:

```
 df1['admissiontime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['admissiontime'])
 df2['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['datetime'])

df2['diff'] = df2['datetime'].sub(df2['id'].map(df1.set_index('id')['admissiontime']))
```

Comment: Great, it does work if there is several differents 'datetime' in df2 for a same id right?

Comment: @Gwénolé exactly, only necessary unique id in df1.